# xamarin for android throws NullReferenceException when trying to request location updates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't seem to figure out, why is this causing an exception.

```
GPSListener gps = new GPSListener(); // <- implements ILocationListener interface
(LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService).RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 0, 0, gps); // <- System.NullReferenceException
```

Calling `IsProviderEnabled` for the "gps" provider returns `true`.

`GetSystemService` does also return a valid LocationManager and not a null. `gps` object is also not null. `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are also added to the manifest.

The call stack

```
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V (_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz) [0x0001c] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23
at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(intptr,intptr)
```

The internal exception message is `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

How can i find out more information what is actually not set in this situation. And how could i fix it. The error happens both in emulator (API 30) and physical phone with Android 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your app has been granted the permission about the location by the user, not only declare it in the AndroidManifest.xml. And you can add the following code into the oncreate method of the activity to do that.

```
 var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

In addition, if you call the method in the background service, you need to add the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` in the AndroidManifest.xaml and use the following code:

```
var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
```

Comment: I was also getting `The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Essentials'` error, even tho i had added the reference. I have created a new xamarin project and copied all files except the csproj and it seems to have fixed. The popup asking for location permission is now seen and granting it does not throw any errors now.